# I want to send the input value of the direction key to the character class through the bridging class that implements the interface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface

#### Premise

I want to send the input value of the direction key to the character class through the bridging class.

#### What you want to achieve

- I want to relay the value
- Pass the value using `Interface`

#### Problems / Error messages that are occurring

`Public float LInputH => _input.MovementFacadeInputH` of `CharacterClass` gives the following error.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

#### Applicable source code

[image: Architecture]

```
public class MobileInput: MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MovementInputH {get; private set;}
    public float MovementInputV {get; private set;}
    
    private void Update ()
    {
        MovementInputH = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        MovementInputV = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
    }
    
}
```

```
public interface IClientInput
{
    public float MovementFacadeInputH {get;}
    public float MovementFacadeInputV {get;}
}

public class InputFacade: MonoBehaviour, IClientInput
{
    [SerializeField] private MobileInput _mobileInput;
    
    public float MovementFacadeInputH =>                 _mobileInput.MovementInputH;
    public float MovementFacadeInputV => _mobileInput.MovementInputV;
}
```

```
public class Character: MonoBehaviour
{
    private IClientInput _input = new InputFacade ();

    public float LInputH => _input.MovementFacadeInputH
    public float LInputV => _input.MovementFacadeInputV;
}
```

#### What I tried

I changed it to this one, but I got the same error.

```
public class Character: MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject _inputFacade;
    private IClientInput _input;
    
    public float LInputH => _input.MovementFacadeInputH;
    public float LInputV => _input.MovementFacadeInputV;
    
    private void InputInit ()
    {
        _inputFacade = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Input");
        _input = _inputFacade.GetComponent <IClientInput> ();
    }
    
    private void Awake ()
    {
        InputInit ();
    }
}
```

Apparently it's wrong to get the value from Intarface, but I can't think of what to do.

Comment: I do not know if you are familiar with Unity new input system, but it solves this problem completely. You can have a complete facade of all the keys on the keyboard and android, as well as other controllers.

Comment: @KiynL 
Thank you for your reply.
I want to implement it as designed as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In unity, `GetComponent<T>()` does not work with interfaces.

I've had some luck with `GetComponent(typeof(Interface))` which you could try use.

As the comments pointed out, you are probably better using the new input system package as it seems to have already solved this problem.